# Using java to count occurrences of letters in string

Tags: java

Recently I did a problem where I found whether a character could be found in a string. I was wondering how to use Java to count the occurrence of EVERY letter in a string and then print it alphabetically? So for example, if the string is "alabama" then the function will return "a:4, b:1, l:1, m:1"

Comment: Suggestion: `TreeMap<Character, Integer>`

Comment: Really? You wonder that? It wasn't suggested you find out by someone like ... a teacher?

Comment: @NishantShreshth i want to assign each letter a number ('a' is 0, 'b' is 1, 'c' is 2, etc). Then, i want to use a for loop to move through the string and add each letter to an array i named count. so 'a' will go in count[0]. 'l' will go in count[11], etc. if count[x] is empty, set count[x]=1. If count[x]!=0, then count[x]++. i don't know how to easily convert the alphabet into numbers from 1-26 though.

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15010706/edit) code into the question & use code formatting.  It is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
TreeMap<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

for (char c: str.toCharArray())
{
  Integer i = map.get(c);
  if (i == null)
    i = 0;
  map.put(c, i+1);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

If the numbers are limited to 'a' to 'z' or the ASCII range (0-255), it would be more efficient to store it in an array instead (the code has the same idea).

Comment: Why can't use use `Map#containsKey` method?

Comment: @RohitJain Why would I want to? Wouldn't that require an additional lookup (one `containsKey`, one `get`)?

Comment: Looking for a key in a map in as `O(1)` operation I think. And it's an intended way to check whether a key is there in the map or not, I think. Makes your intent much clearer.

Comment: @RohitJain `O(1)` is only for `HashMap`, `TreeMap` is `O(log n)`, but I found `HashMap` to be slower in some practical applications because the constant factor is high.

Comment: actually, containsKey does exactly the same as get(c) but instead of returning the key (return key), it returns (return key!=null)
`public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return getEntry(key) != null;
    }`

Comment: Why not just use a 26 element array?  That really is O(1).

Comment: @BaileyS I briefly suggested it above, but the problem is that if it covers the entire Unicode range, the array would be pretty big.

Comment: This is true.  Profiling would likely show that TreeMap is just as fast here anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another example using maps.

```
String myString = "alabama";        
NavigableMap<Character, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
for(char c : myString.toCharArray()) {
    if(myMap.get(c)==null){
        myMap.put(c, 1);
    }else {
        myMap.put(c, myMap.get(c)+1);
    }           
}       
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue() );
    if(!myMap.lastKey().equals(entry.getKey())){
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
```

or...

**UPDATE**

```
String str = "alabama";     
Map<Character, Integer> auxMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if(auxMap.get(c)==null){
            auxMap.put(c, 1);
        }else {
            auxMap.put(c, auxMap.get(c)+1);
        }           
    }   
    System.out.println(auxMap);
```

Comment: A little bit complex to do a simple job, no?

Comment: if you are familiar with maps it ain't that complex. I can't think of any other way of doing it to match the exact expected result asked, with less code.